# hide/ show controls in View controllers

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

My application gathers input from users and hence it is full of Labels, text boxes and buttons and I have to show or hide set of labels and text boxes based on certain conditions.

To accomplish it, I did the following.

1. Set fixed height (lets say 30) for all the controls
2. Set height constraint on each of the controls and created an outlet to the height constraint in the ViewController
3. Alter the heightConstraint.constant value programatically (between 0.0 and 30.0) based on the scenarios.

Having programmed like this, it is very difficult for me if there is any change in layout. (i.e., if user requested to add/remove any particular control from the view Controller).

I am using Auto Layout constraints. Could anyone suggest if there is a better way to accomplish my goal.

I am using IOS9 and Swift.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UITableViewController with static cells for this case.

For hide/show row or section, you can change the size in the  `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

UITableViewController automatically manages the layout and with static cell you can even create outlet for all the controls.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a table for this? It has mechanisms for inserting and deleting rows and would manage the layouting for you - only part you'd need to care about are the contents of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making IBOutlets to the height constraints of all the views that you might need to hide, you can just use the `hidden` property of UIViews to hide/show the view.

In case you need the view to make space for other views, you could set a simple animation and move the view out of screen bounds. You might face issues with layout constraints but it's surely worth the effort from a UI/UX perspective.

Additionally, if you know that you don't need a view any more you can even remove the view from it's superview.

Comment: Hi, ya I can use hidden property of the UIViews. But when they are hidden the space that the views occupied should be filled by the following views. If I use hidden it wont auto align and we can see the spaces right